# Remove The Child Tag Name not a value

Tags: php, javascript, xml, xslt

i have this type of xml file:-

```
<product>
   <node>
       <region_id>
                <node>1</node>
       </region_id>
       <region_time>
                <node>27</node>
                <node>02</node>
                <node>2013</node>
       </region_time>
   </node>
</ptroduct>
```

i want to change in them in like something this type:-

```
<product>
      <region_id>1</region_id>
      <region_time>27,02,2013</region_time>
</product>
```

i want to Remove `<Node>` just want to there value as above

Comment: In PHP, Javascript or XSLT?

Comment: In PHP there's `DOMDocument`; In Javascript - do you need IE8 support? What have you tried? I would do some manual iteration; In XSLT - no idea.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i am not tried any thing but i think its possible with replace fuction...

Comment: @JackPhp once again, what language?

Comment: @JackPhp, See a pure XSLT 1.0 solution -- and even more -- it is correct :)

Comment: @JanDvorak sorry php and java script...

Comment: @JackPhp you mean, in both, or we can choose?

Comment: @JanDvorak if as replace function use PHP right... and in my required xslt and php any of both... thanks for clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node[position()>1]/text()">
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<product>
    <node>
        <region_id>
            <node>1</node>
        </region_id>
        <region_time>
            <node>27</node>
            <node>02</node>
            <node>2013</node>
        </region_time></node>
</product>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<product>
   <region_id>1</region_id>
   <region_time>27,02,2013</region_time>
</product>
```

Comment: its return simple text like 1 27,02,2013

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - I have a clarification in your xslt, I tried it out and it works correctly but what is the purpose <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /> ? What does it do? I am learning xslt now and would like you to clarify this for me

Comment: @Abi, You need to read about the identity rule. This is the most fundamental XSLT design pattern. http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html

Answer (score 2):

The following example will do the job.

Imagine you have the following files:

*test.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<product>
   <node>
       <region_id>
                <node>1</node>
       </region_id>
       <region_time>
                <node>27</node>
                <node>02</node>
                <node>2013</node>
       </region_time>
   </node>
</product>
```

*test.xsl* **Updated**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- from dimitre\'s xsl.thanks -->
 <xsl:template match="node[position()>1]/text()">
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*xslt.php*

```
$sourcedoc = new DOMDocument();
$sourcedoc->load('test.xml');

$stylesheet = new DOMDocument();
$stylesheet->load('test.xsl');

// create a new XSLT processor and load the stylesheet
$xsltprocessor = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltprocessor->importStylesheet($stylesheet);

// save the new xml file
file_put_contents('test-translated.xml', $xsltprocessor->transformToXML($sourcedoc));
```

Comment: sec! there's a small bug in it.. haven't read the question correctly  will fix the xsl...

Comment: hey its good but i want other type like xml tree wise output <product><region_id>1</region_id><region_time>27,02,2013</region_time></product>

Comment: Yes I've mentioned this. I would suggest that you use my php code and dimitries (great) xsl .. this should work .. (I have tested it)

Comment: Also note that you need the php5-xsl extension installed to get the above code work. (the exact name of the extension may differ on your OS)

Comment: still i have not getting perfect o/p  this is last o/p 1 27,02,2013

Comment: open the source code view in your browser ;) The browser will 'eat' the xml tags

Comment: check my update.. Use `file_put_contents()` for that. Also make sure that you (the webserver) have write permissions

Comment: thanks its work exactly i am new for this then i give more help thanks again and for your best replay of comments +1k

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script which does the following

1. Remove all spaces and new line characters (SO, that all the contents are in a single line).
2. Use string replace, to replace `'</node><node>'` with ','
3. Use string replace, to replace `'</node>'` with '' and `'<node>'` with ''

Done!!

You can use this in PHP or Javascript, by using the appropriate syntax.

Comment: You are trying to flatten the file and use regex. This completely slows the processing down when you can use much more efficient methods (ie DOMDocument, SXE). This is not right at all. Should I also mention that the desired coding language hasn't even been mentioned.

Comment: I would rather stick to DOM manipulation than rely on string manipulation.

Comment: Well, about the coding language, question has been tagged as PHP, Javascript, Hence the assumption.

Comment: @Archer question has been tagged as PHP, Javascript, hence this is not a real question (until the asker decides, that is)

Comment: @JanDvorak, Ok Jan  :)  ... Apart from the tags .. Also, His username is Jack **Php**, ... still i am waiting for asker to decide. :)